# problemas com instalação de wordpress em servidor com cpanel

Tags: mysql, wordpress, dns

**Estou a tentar ajuda uma ONG como voluntário no sentido de:**

- *recuperar o seu site, após um incidente com seu serviço de hospedagem na web (sabotagem interna por alguém que deixou a organização)*
- *o facto de não ter de momento acesso ao source torna as coisas ainda mais difíceis;*

**fiz o seguinte:**

- *instalei o mamp no meu Macintosh*
- *para tornar as coisas fáceis e muito rápidas, desenvolvi um site mínimo no Wordpress com o conteúdo que me foi fornecido em menos de duas horas.*
- *comprou-se um novo domínio da web (eles também foram sabotados no domínio)*
- *falei com um amigo que administra uma empresa de TI para nos fornecer um serviço gratuito de hospedagem na web, que já está mapeado para o novo domínio.*
- *devo notar que o novo domínio não se encontra mapeado para o serviço de hospedagem web ao nível das dns*

**Em relação à migração:**

- _primeiro tentei fazer backup dos meus dados do mamp no ftp public_html server que está executando o painel, bem como clonar o banco de dados e migrá-lo)_
- *não consegui aceder a instalação do WordPress através do endereço IP*

**Como a primeira iteração do site é bastante mínimal, e basicamente posso migrar o conteúdo para o WordPress:**.

- *eu apaguei a instalação anterior em seu banco de dados*
- _clonei uma cópia Wordpress em branco em public_html / site (onde o site substitui o Wordpress_
- *creio uma base de dados em mysql, bem como um usuário, e eu associei o usuário com o banco de dados*
- *editei o arquivo wp-config.php e adicionei o nome do banco de dados, usuário, senha*

**Eu adicionei em alguns campos perto do final do documento com:**

- define ('WP_HOME', 'http: // ip / ~ user_name’);
- define ('WP_SITEURL', 'http: // ip / ~ user_name’);

**Depois tentei acessar o site via http: // ip / ~ user_name onde:**.

- _o argumento ip e o ~ user_name são substituídos pelos valores apropriados_
- *não funcionou*

**Eu tentei :**

- *Ipaddress / site / wp-admin*
- *não funcionou*

**Agradeço toda a ajuda possível devido ao facto de:**

- *isto dever estar concluído amanhã*

**Eu devo notar que:**

- *o serviço de hospedagem na web não está realmente cooperando a nível de assistência técnica*

Comment: Pesquise sobre como migrar o WP de host local para um server web, provavelmente vc vai ter que usar um plugin tipo o akeeba pra "zipar" seu site e depois descompactar o site no webserver. Assim vc vai usar só o phpmyadmin do cpanel para construir o banco. Procure tutorias de como migrar o WordPress de servidor

Comment: já consegui dar a volta. o unico erro que cometi, foi a forma como instanciei o username, no endereço de ip, que deveria apontar para o username da conta de alojamento e nao para o username da base de dados. resolvida a confusão já estou a tratar de migrar os conteudos todos

Answer (score 0):

já descobri onde estava o problema. ao fazer um http request no site, quando se coloca ip/~username, username é o user do servidor ftp. era a única coisa que estava de facto a falhar. fazendo isso, chama-se a pasta public_html